The gguf file imported into Ollama produces irrelevant responses
enter image description here
I successfully imported the MiniCPM-2B-dpo-bf16-gguf.gguf model into Ollama and got it running. However, during inference, I noticed that the model produces nonsensical responses and hallucinations are quite severe. See the attached screenshot for details.
Rollback llama.cpp to an older version.
I hope to convert my fine-tuned model to a gguf file format and import it into Ollama for normal Q&A.
